# Determining if an Array contains Duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I'm trying to determine of an array of strings has duplicates by making a second array, adding the elements of the first to it, and then checking if that element is already in the second array. I'm not sure how to syntactically do that properly though.

code so far:

```
    public static boolean duplicates(String[] DUP)
    {
         String[] fresh = {};
         for(int i=0; i<DUP.length; i++)
             if(fresh.contains(DUP.charAt[i]))
                 return true;
             else
                 fresh += DUP.charAt[i];
         return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String[] DUP = {"a","b","b","c"};
         System.out.println("Array DUP contains duplicates: " + duplicates(DUP)
    }
```

Comment: @güriösä I don't know how to properly implement the algorithm syntactically.

Comment: That seems pointless, you already have an array with the elements in it, you just need to not check the current index. If you're going to make a second data structure, why not consider a map? That way your lookup is O(1).

Comment: You need to be more specific--*syntax* is the easy part. It might make sense to look at a Java array tutorial (but you might want a list instead).

Comment: You have noticed, that DUP has no charAt method, Strings have one. I think, you meant `DUP[i]`. Then you're treating `fresh` like a number (`fresh +=`), but you can't manipulate arrays that way. You have to give them the proper size when you create them, you can access elements only per index. They also have no `contains` method, you might want to take e.g. an ArrayList for that instead.

Comment: I'd propose to work through those topics separately from some tutorials or so: Strings, Arrays, Lists

Comment: You are mixing up many things. I suggest you start with [the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical sets have no duplicates. Thus, you can use the java implementation of sets, e. g. [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) and [java.util.HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html):

```java
String[] array = {"a", "a", "b"};
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
System.out.println(set.size() < array.length);
```

... does print `true` as the duplicate `"a"` got dropped.